# How to make MySQL read my.cnf again without restarting?

Tags: mysql

Is there such a command?

I've modified my.cnf,and I don't want to stop/start MySQL.

Comment: Maybe you should post this question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you have to restart your MySQL Server, but there are some configuration variables that can changed without restarting: [dynamic system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dynamic-system-variables.html)

Comment: Set global log_slow_query=1 is what I want!

Answer (score 3):

As far as POSIX goes, [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (which normally tells a program designed to run in the background after starting to reload its config) flushes privileges. Reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/flush.html). That's actually as it should be, if you ran the service in the foreground and got disconnected, you'd probably want that to happen.

That leaves us with [SIGUSR(1 or 2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGUSR1_and_SIGUSR2) which have been [known to crash](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25526) the service.

In short, make due with the tools provided :) Any time you are dealing with a service that makes use of more than primitive [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), its a good idea to just re-start the service when you make configuration changes. Lots of running threads need to complete their work, die and be re-born .. yet another race to a mutual exclusive lock would take more time than just re-starting it, considering that every running thread would have to modify its behavior and understanding of its universe [in situ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ). That leads to deadlock, quickly and a zombie parent.

Keep in mind that most RDBMS use their own buffering, which is typically handled by the kernel for most other services. You can't just ask a thread to speak Spanish when it once spoke English, or vice versa, depending on what you changed in the configuration.

At least, not without reincarnating the parent.. hence, just re-start.

Answer (score 0):

Install the RubyGem `mysql_manager` (`sudo gem install mysql_manager`) and then run the command:

```
mysql-manager --reload-my-cnf --reload-my-cnf:config /etc/my.cnf --log:level DEBUG
```

For more options, run `mysql-manager --help`.

You might need to specify an alternative `--db:dsn`, `--db:username`, or `--db:password`.

Read more about it here: https://github.com/osterman/mysql_manager